# Adding bool to a file is turning all bool types into errors

Tags: flutter, dart

This is weird but when I add the following code to a file all of the other bool type variables get this error:

```
  final bool 24aSellerDisclosureDeadline = false;
  final bool 24bDueDiligenceDeadline = false;
```

If I remove this code all of the other bool types go back to normal. What is going on here and how do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot name an identifier starting with a number. See [Important concepts](https://dart.dev/language#important-concepts).

> *Identifiers* can start with a letter or underscore (_), followed by any combination of those characters plus digits.